# How can I use ko.toJs method without computed properties in knockout mapping?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to convert viewModel to Json object. But I don't want to map computed properties.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are a few options, if you are going to convert it to JSON:

1. if you are using constructor functions for your object, then you can override the `.toJSON` function to control which properties to output.  Here is an article on it: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FE4HX/.
2. in KO 2.1, when using `ko.toJSON` the second and third arguments are now passed to `JSON.stringify`.  Here is some documentation on the arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify.  This means that you can pass the second argument (`replacer`) with either an array of properties to include or a function that processes the key/values.  Here is the same sample using this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/huyLe/.
3. Another option that I use frequently, is to define computeds that you don't want in your JSON output as sub-observables.  Observables are functions, which are objects, so you can actually define observables on observables.  Like:

-

```
this.name = ko.observable("Bob");
this.name.formatted = ko.computed(...);
```

Now when converting to JSON, `formatted` will be naturally lost as `name` gets converted to its value.  Here is the same sample again: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/peEGG/.  Usually I use this when it is meta-data about an observable (`isValid`, `isEditing`, etc.).

Comment: That third option saved my ass. I love you, Niemeyer.

Comment: Similar to José Angel Yánez answer below, here's a way to use a replacer method like in 2nd option above, but to create an JSON object (like ko.toJS):
  ko.toJS2 = function (model, replacer) {
    return JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(model, replacer));
  }

Comment: Wish I knew the third one earlier! Thank you, Niemeyer.

Comment: let me add my name to the list of those loving the sub-observable.  thanks very many.

Comment: Third option should be the first one, till now I didn't think about it even though I am using validation plugin which uses same approach for isValid function

Comment: Lol @Niemeyer, the third option saved  me.. don't know how in the world you came up with the fact that the mapping plugin would ignore that sub-observable but thanks!

Comment: I know we're not supposed to tack on with "me too" comments... but option #3 is so slick that I spontaneously just said to my coworkers that I "heart" Ryan Niemeyer.

Comment: the #3 is really witty, but quite ugly in terms of design I think customizing the serializer is a better approach. (but I need to admit it's tempting)

Answer (score 7):

This will also work, it will just ignore anything with a 'mappedProperties' in it, for duck-type naysayers remember you shouldn't have mappedProperties as part of your code since you're using knockout. Therefore it should work.

```
/* Use this serializer function along with ko.toJS to produce clean JSON objects. */
ko.toJS2 = function (model)
{
     return JSON.parse(ko.toJSON(model, modelSerializer));
}

function modelSerializer(key, value)
{
if (isSerializable(value))
    return value;
else
    return;
}

function isSerializable(object) {
    if (object == null) return true;
    if (typeof object == 'function') return false;
    if (object.mappedProperties != null) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
var goodLookingJson = ko.toJS2(whateverModel);
```

Comment: Thanks, hat-tip for posting code! Just to clarify, your `ko.toJS2` function returns pure javascript objects, not JSON strings, right? Would you just strip out the JSON.parse call to create a `ko.toJSON2` (or `ko.toCleanJSON` as I'd call it)?